# Неправильно отображается табуляция при просмотре txt файла в браузере

Tags: php, файлы

Есть строка, которую хочу записать в файл с соблюдением табуляции

```
$str = "114056071\t01.05.2017 01:15:48\t37.212.32.231\n
        114056575\t01.03.2017 02:15:48\t221.12.52.21\n
        114060794\t01.01.2017 02:15:48\t11.12.51.221\n";
file_put_contents('file.txt', $str);
```

Но при просмотре этого файла в браузере, выводит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как сделать так, чтобы выводилось вот так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот содержимое файла в нотпаде, где видно что здесь есть табуляция
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кодировка файла: UTF8 без BOM, пробовал и просто UTF8 - все-равно тот-же результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выстави

```
content-type: text/plain
```

Если уж нельзя сделать в css

```
white-space: pre;
```